# Making Applications using the spotify API?

Tags: c#, api, spotify

I want to start making a simple program using the spotify API, a simple thing like showing the current song in a textbox or something. Where should i start doing this? Are there any tutorials around here? I was planning to code it in C#.

Comment: did you tried ? any full source code sample about it?

Answer (score 2):

Included in the distribution are a couple of example files designed to get you started easily.

You can download them [here](http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/).

Answer (score 1):

I would say start by finding a good C# wrapper for Spotify, there are tons of them on github. This will save you time by avoiding making HTTP calls manually and parsing JSON back.

I just finished on a small Rails app for Spotify and used rspotify gem for it, i know it is not in C# but it will give you a general idea of what i am talking about.